# I need a wait command in VB

Tags: vb.net

hello am writing a code in VB to send commands to cygwin terminal and i want the code to wait for the first command to wait untill the first command is excuted (or wait about 2 min) and then continue to the next command, the a part of the code:

```
Shell("C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe")
SendKeys.Send("tracert -h  " & _h & " " & domain.Text & " > temp1.txt{ENTER}")
```

the program should wait 2 min here and then continue to the next command, thanks.

Comment: I see you rolled back the tag change. The vb tag is generic, and is not normally used. You would have a better chance of getting an acceptable answer if you tag your question with the flavor of Visual Basic that you are using(vb6, vb.net, vbscript).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(120000)
```

The value is in millseconds.

Comment: hey aphoria, you're really my savior :) thanks a lot, i started writing a wait function to do it and it was terrible , your really worked great, so thanks agan.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
Wscript.Sleep 120000
```